# Clojure: Marginalia: Multi Page Documentation

Tags: clojure, marginalia

### Question

```
(run-marginalia {})
```

produces a single file, docs/uberdoc.html

I would prefer it to produce many files in docs/*, one per *.clj file

### Motivation:

I really like marginalia. I have recently started using it, and it's causing me to *want* to write documentation, as impossible as that sounds.

However, I have this problem that whenever I write docs, and refresh, and reload uberdoc.html, I lose the part of the doc I was previously looking at. Thus, I would prefer a system where each *.clj file had it's on *.html file for documentation. Is this possible with marginalia 0.7.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mutlidoc functionality in a previous version, but it is not at command line in the latest version. However, by running something like `(multidoc! "./docs" (find-processable-file-paths "./src" #"\.clj$") {})` you should get directory of individual files.

Comment: The latest version of Marginalia (0.7.1) takes a `--multi` flag that basically runs this function.  More info at http://blog.fogus.me/2012/06/08/announcing-marginalia-v0-7-1/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/weavejester/codox is another Clojure documentation tool (which gives separate pages - see http://number23.github.com/commons-lib/)

Comment: is there an example somewhere?  i couldn't see one at the link.

Comment: add to project.clj's `:plugins` like this: https://github.com/number23/commons-lib/blob/master/project.clj, output docs: http://number23.github.com/commons-lib/